# Best way to combine stored procedure and query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am making a report in SSRS and some of the data is being obtained from a query, while other data such as db size is being taken from stored procedure (sp_databases)...

How can I join this data?

I was wondering what would be the best way to join these? Temp table? To my knowledge I cannot use a view since they cant call stored procedures, am I correct?

Comment: Using a SQL Script may be ... another main procedure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pull the data you want from the stored procedure into a temp table and use that temp table along with your query in a stored proc you can call from the SSRS report.

This question might help with the first part. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score -1):

You can call the results of the SP like this:

```
SELECT tmp.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'my_sqlserver_name';'my_sqluser_login';'my_sqlpass word',
'EXEC mydatabase.dbo.mystoredprodedure') AS tmp
```

And then join or union to your other query.